# Induction on the length of a lambda-term

Tags: lambda-calculus

Let M be a λ -term, with length m, that is: m = lgh(M).

Well... I think "induction on lgh(M)" means the same as "finite induction on m".
But I'm not sure.

I ask for help.

Comment: How do you define the length of a λ-term? This is not a standard notion, afaik.

Comment: (a) lgh(a) = 1   for atoms a;      (b)  lgh(MN) = lgh(M) + lgh(N) ;    (c) lgh( λx.M) = 1 + lgh(M)

Comment: Then $\mathrm{lgh}(M)$ is the number of variables and λ's in $M$, and your induction is on this integer (induction hypothesis: the property is true for all $M'$ with fewer variables and λ's). “Induction on $M$” would be a structural induction, on the top-level constructor of $M$ (induction hypothesis: the property is true for all strict subterm of $M$).